# Does X-Frame-options works for local files too?

Tags: html, file, http, protocols, x-frame-options

I load an html file ("file://...") in a web browser: in this file there's an `<iframe>`. Inside this iframe, I must load some remote content. I know the content I will load is protected by the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header, that can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`.

The question is simple: will the X-Frame-Options HTTP header work even if I load my page locally as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine, I made a little test, then I forgot about this question